# SQL Query to get 1 latest record per member based on a latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database Like this :

```
---------------------------------------------------
| MemberID | IntrCode | InstruReply | CreatedDate |  ...other 2 more columns
---------------------------------------------------
| 6        | 1        | Activated   | 26 FEB 2014 |
| 7        | 2        | Cancelled   | 25 FEB 2014 |
| 6        | 2        | Cancelled   | 15 FEB 2014 |
| 7        | 1        | Activated   | 03 FEB 2014 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Now based on the `CreatedDate` and the `instCode`, I need a query that returns the results as follows based on `instCode` as parameter.

When `@IntrCode = 1`, I need only active `MemberID` on the latest(`CreatedDate`).

PS: please note member 7 is cancelled when checking latest (CreatedDate).

Output

```
---------------------------------------------------
| MemberID | IntrCode | InstruReply | CreatedDate |
---------------------------------------------------
| 6        | 1        | Activated   | 26 FEB 2014 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I wrote the below Query and I cant show other columns.(I appreciate all your help)

```
SELECT MemberID, MAX(CreatedDate) AS LatestDate FROM MyTable GROUP BY MemberID
```

Comment: whats the primary key of the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY MemberID Order By CreatedDate DESC) RN
  FROM MyTable WHERE InstruReply = 'Activated' AND IntrCode = @IntrCode
) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
```

**Method 2 :**

```
 SELECT * FROM
 (
   Select MemberID,max(CreatedDate) as LatestDate from MyTable group by MemberID
 ) As s INNER Join MyTable T ON T.MemberID = S.MemberID AND T.CreatedDate = s.LatestDate
 WHere T.InstruReply = 'Activated' T.IntrCode = @IntrCode
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7413b6/17)

**Output**

```
---------------------------------------------------
| MemberID | IntrCode | InstruReply | CreatedDate |
---------------------------------------------------
| 6        | 1        | Activated   | 26 FEB 2014 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and the [`ROW_NUMBER` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
With CTE As
(
    SELECT t.*, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY MemberID Order By CreatedDate DESC)
    FROM MyTable t
    WHERE IntrCode = @IntrCode
)
SELECT MemberID, IntrCode, InstruReply, CreatedDate
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7413b6/4/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This way you can select whole row for each member with latest date.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM MyTable t2 
                  WHERE t2.CreatedDate > t1.CreatedDate
                  AND t1.MemberID = t2.MemberID)
AND IntrCode = @IntrCode
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;with TempData as (Select MemberId, IntrCode   ,InstruReply,CreatedDate  , MemberCount =ROW_NUMBER()
                over(PARTITION By MemberId Order By CreatedDate desc)
                From MyTable 
                )

Select *
From TempData
Where MemberCount =1
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you wrote is simply missing a `WHERE` clause which will help you to filter the data you need:

```
SELECT MemberID, MAX(CreatedDate) AS LatestDate
FROM MyTable
WHERE IntrCode = @IntrCode
  AND InstruReply = 'Activated'
GROUP BY MemberID
```